# Run a build task only when changes have been pulled from a git repository

Tags: git, ansible

I have a C++ program hosted in Bitbucket git repository that I'm compiling with CMake. The current play can be seen below. It works fine except `build`-task is run every time the play is run. Instead I'd like `build`-task to run only when new software version is pulled by [git](http://docs.ansible.com/git_module.html)-module. How I can tell in `build`-task if `clone`-task found new version ?

```
---
# tasks of role: foo

- name: clone repository
  git: repo=git@bitbucket.org:foo/foo.git
       dest={{ foo.dir }}
       accept_hostkey=yes

- name: create build dir
  file: state=directory path={{ foo.build_dir }}

- name: build
  command: "{{ item }} chdir={{ foo.build_dir }}"
  with_items:
    - cmake ..
    - make
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can register variable with output of `clone` task and invoke `build` task when state of `clone` task is changed

For example:

```
---
# tasks of role: foo

- name: clone repository
  git: repo=git@bitbucket.org:foo/foo.git
       dest={{ foo.dir }}
       accept_hostkey=yes
  register: gitclone

- name: create build dir
  file: state=directory path={{ foo.build_dir }}

- name: build
  command: "{{ item }} chdir={{ foo.build_dir }}"
  with_items:
    - cmake ..
    - make
  when: gitclone.changed
```

Comment: Works like a charm ! In fact I'm already using `register`-variables to record the output of several `command` outputs, but I didn't realized I can use it to capture the output record of any module (I'm using `-vv` so I easily see what's available).

Comment: Wait, this is going to keep state between runs?

Comment: No, this is to receive `notification` when git will receive updates from remote repository.
State could not be saved

Comment: What if there are multiple steps and I want to trigger a handler if any of them return changed?

Comment: when: step1.changed or step2.changed or step3.changed

Comment: If the build was to fail, would a subsequent run not try to build anymore, since gitclone.changed wouldn't be true anymore? Or is Ansible smart enough to handle this correctly?